# WkHtmlToPdf Component, problem with Auth

Tags: cakephp, components, wkhtmltopdf

I'm trying to use the [WkHtmlToPdf Component](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/jwswart/2010/04/09/wkhtmltopdf-component), it seems like a nice tool when facing the problem of generating pdf files.

However - I can't get it to work with the Auth Component. The problem is that I always get the login page generated to pdf. I'm logged, the action is allowed in beforeFilter and it still somehow gets into the way of it.

### EDIT:

AppController:

```
var $components = array('Auth', 'Session');

function beforeFilter()
  {
  $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login');

  if (!$this->Auth->user())
    {
    $this->layout = 'login';
    }  
  }
```

Controller:

```
var $components = array('WkHtmlToPdf');

function beforeFilter() // I am logged in, so this shouldn't even be needed
  {
  $this->Auth->allow('pdf');
  }

function pdf()
  {
  $this->WkHtmlToPdf->createPdf();
  }

// this function is required for wkhtmltopdf to retrieve
// the viewdump once it's rendered
function getViewDump($fileName)
  {
  $this->WkHtmlToPdf->getViewDump($fileName);
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Paul

Comment: Can you post your app controller and the controller where the component is used? Just the relevant bits will do

Comment: Shouldn't you be calling `parent::beforFilter()` in your controller?

Comment: Well, yeah - but it doesn't change anything, the beforeFilter in Controller shouldn't be needed, since I'm logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, you have to allow the `getViewDump` method. It doesn't seem to work with Auth, but there is no threat with allowing it for everyone, and it works.

controller:

```
function beforeFilter()
    {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $this->Auth->allow('getViewDump');
    }
```